# SwiftUI WheelPicker doesn't update connected binding while scrolling

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

I'm trying to get a WheelPicker to continuously update the value of the connected minutes variable while it's still scrolling. I'm basically looking for the same behaviour as in the Apple Clock App.
Currently it only updates the value when it comes to a standstill, which is problematic when the user continues in my app to the next part, as the selection hasn't been updated yet and remains at the default value.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var minutes: Int = 1

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("", selection: $minutes) {
                ForEach(1..<120, id: \.self) { minute in
                    Text("\(minute) minutes").tag(minute)
                        .dynamicTypeSize(.medium)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

I tried using an UIPickerView, but this displays the same behaviour. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Maybe something with [`Combine`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine) and [`.onRecieve`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onreceive(_:perform:))?